# How to Mount and Unmount encrypted folder in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, mount, encryption, ecryptfs

I made an encrypted folder in my Home Directory following this method https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-encrypt-directories-with-ecryptfs-on-ubuntu-16-04/
But now I can't understand how to mount this folder when I need. I tried using `sudo mount -t ecryptfs /home/username/Secure /home/username/Secure` But doesn't this just re-encrypt the folder? How do I mount and unmount it properly?

Initially I wanted a folder that will stay encrypted after I log in and will ask the password to mount (Prefereably in GUI). Please also suggest if there is an easier way in 18.04.

I saw some GUI method of doing it but those are mostly backdated.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-encrypt-directories-with-ecryptfs-on-ubuntu-16-04/

That howtoforge page says:

> When you do this **for the first time**, you will have to answer a few questions:

So, presumably, when you do it **the second time** it **won't** ask you "a few questions", but only one question: "Passphrase:"

Comment: Well no. That command actually asks all of those questions again and everytime which is confusing.

Comment: @Bluebug you might be doing something wrong.  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ecryptfs.html.en says the same thing as howtoforge.com.  Best to edit your answer and **show** us how you encrypt it the first time, and then it asks the same questions again the second time.